# WPFToolkit.Extended - where are the tools?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Steps I've taken:

1. I'm using .NET 4.0
2. I've got to [codeplex](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/84227) and downloaded the first "Extended WPF Toolkit Binaries".
3. Number 2 added this file "ExtendedWPFToolkit_Binaries.zip" to here: C:\Users\myName\Downloads\
4. I then extracted the .dll file and put it here: C:\downloads\WPFToolkit.Extended.dll
5. In the WPF project I Browsed (i.e to the dll in step 4) for an extra reference and it now has an extra ref to "WPFToolkit.Extended
6. In the MainWindow.xaml.cs file I've added this"using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;"
7. In the App.xaml file I've added this "xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"

Is step 7 ok?

What else do I need to do to see the tools in the Toolbox?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Go to the toolbox tab (ctrl+alt+x), right click on it and "Add Tab", type the name you want for it (ex: "WPF Extended Toolkit").

Then right click again on it and "Choose Items..". Browse to find the dll you just downloaded and click OK
[image: Choose Toolbox Items dialog]

And.. that's it.

[image: Extended WPF Toolkit toolbox tab]

Comment: Glad to hear that, enjoy the extended toolkit.

Comment: Ok - I'm now at home using VS C# Express and this doesn't work!? I get to the final stage above "Choose items..." and all the controls appear in the "Choose Toolbox items" window and then when I press ok nothing crashes but no controls appear in the new bit of the toolbox!

Answer (score 0):

Use Nuget for the Extended WPF Toolkit -- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit