# Cannot locate resource WPF Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'd like to use WPF Toolkit in my C# WPF application. I installed the very latest version using NuGet and also added the controls to the designer following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115189/wpftoolkit-extended-where-are-the-tools) (I used `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll` as source for the controls), and am finally encountering the problem that nothing is being displayed in the designer when adding xceed controls to the grid, the only error I get using this sample code:

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" BusyContent="Downloading email..." >
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource SampleContent}"/>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

> Cannot locate resource "styleablewindow/themes/aero2.normalcolor.xaml

I guess it's worth mentioning the use of `Caliburn.Micro` and MVVM in WPF. However, I don't know which resource this refers to, where it is supposed to be located at, and finally how to get Xceed working.

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to your project(App project) from GAC to PresentationFramework.Aero2

Comment: All right. I know GAC, but how do I do what you suggested?

Comment: Add the reference, and if that doesn't work try changing in the reference properties to: CopyLocal = True.

Answer (score 0):

As Mishka said, add a reference to PresentationFramework.Aero2. In Visual Studio 2017, you can right-click on the References in your project and choose "Add Reference..." from the context menu. In the dialog that comes up, you can find the PresentationFramework.Aero2 assembly under Assemblies then Framework as pictured below:

[image: Add Reference Dialog]